# HTML all fields required not working

Tags: html

How do I make the form's submit button locate new page if all fields are filled out to the 8 minimum characters required and the radio button being checked. When I fill out fields or leave them blank the submit button does nothing. Thanks for any and all advice.

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action=""><br>

    <h6>Sign up using the form below...</h6><br>
    <label>
        Desired user name: <br>
        <input type="text" name="username" size="15" minlength="8" maxlength="30" required title="8 characters minimum" required />
    </label><br>
    <label>
        Password: <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" size="15" minlength="8" maxlength="30"  required title="8 characters minimum" required/>
    </label><br>
    <label>
        Repeat Password: <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" size="15" minlength="8" maxlength="30" required title="8 characters minimum" required/>
    </label><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" required/> I agree to the terms and service of this website<br><br>

    <input class="account" type="submit" name ="Submit" value="Submit" formnovalidate onClick="window.location = 'http://www.google.com';"/><br><br>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`formnovalidate` is creating the problem, try this out.

```html
<form id="form1" action="https://www.google.com"><br>

    <h6>Sign up using the form below...</h6><br>
    <label>
        Desired user name: <br>
        <input type="text" name="username" size="15" minlength="8" maxlength="30" required title="8 characters minimum" required />
    </label><br>
    <label>
        Password: <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" size="15" minlength="8" maxlength="30"  required title="8 characters minimum" required/>
    </label><br>
    <label>
        Repeat Password: <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" size="15" minlength="8" maxlength="30" required title="8 characters minimum" required/>
    </label><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" required/> I agree to the terms and service of this website<br><br>

    <input class="account" type="submit" name ="Submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
    </form>
```